# python - fuzzy matching, looping through a data set to find corresponding items in the reference set

Tags: python, fuzzy-comparison, fuzzywuzzy

I am trying to learn and implement fuzzy matching in python. I have two data sets which I load as data frames into pandas. Set 1 is the reference set. Set two is the set containing data to match with the reference names. 


I loop through the set_1 items to search for corresponding entries in the reference, but I get an error. I need some help with the error. 

 Am I trying to structure the algorithm in a good way?

My attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import fuzzywuzzy as fuzzy
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

set_1 = pd.read_csv("C:/Folder/file_1.csv")
set_2 = pd.read_csv("C:/Folder/file_2.csv")

query = set_1['name']
choices = set_2['name2']

for query in query:
    match = fuzzy.extractOne(query,choises=choises,scorer=scorer,score_cutoff=cutoff)
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'fuzzywuzzy' has no attribute 'extractOne'
```

Comment: Try replacing the import line with `from fuzzywuzzy import process as fuzzy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the package's [usage](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy#usage) on github, you'll notice that `extractOne` is a function defined in `fuzzywuzzy.process`, so you'll need to import that submodule like so:

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import process  # <-- note the difference
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

set_1 = pd.read_csv("C:/Folder/file_1.csv")
set_2 = pd.read_csv("C:/Folder/file_2.csv")

query = set_1['name']
choices = set_2['name2']

for query in query:
    #       vvvvvvv  note the difference
    match = process.extractOne(query,choises=choises,scorer=scorer,score_cutoff=cutoff)
```

Comment: I changed as suggested above, changed the loop as well to:   for row in names.itertuples():
    print((row[1]))
    match = process.extractOne(row[1],reference,partial_token_set_ratio,score_cutoff=70) and still cannot get it working. This time there is a different error : 
NameError: name 'partial_token_set_ratio' is not defined

Comment: It may be that `fuzzywuzzy` isn't very smart about its imports.  Try adding `from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz` to your imports and see what happens.

Comment: it seems that the apply function is the better way than a loop, as demonstrated here http://blog.keyrus.co.uk/fuzzy_matching_101_part_ii.html